# Thread is being killed by Android system

Tags: android, multithreading

In my android application, I am performing a task in the receiver that listens to BOOT_UP_Completed broadcast. Because the task duration is indefinite and depends on current system time, I performed the task in a different thread. The thread is started in onReceive() method of BOOT_COMPLETED intent. In the thread task, I sleep the thread for 1 second if the check fails to avoid over-utilization of CPU cycles. The run method looks something like below:

```
while (true) {

        if (condition == true) {
            //doSomething
            break;
        }

        Thread.sleep(sleep_duration);   // 1 second
    }
```

When I boot up the device, the thread runs for a while and after that I get the message like below:

```
I/ActivityManager( 3166): Killing 6916:process/1101 (adj 15): bgCount ##41
```

I am not sure why the system is killing the thread. Or why the thread stopped executing. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Do all your main work in a service. Make it 'foreground service' if you want to be sure for it to be running. Start that service from your broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't own a long term thread (more than a few seconds) in a BroadcastReceiver.  Once a BroadcastReceiver ends, Android may kill the app.  To fix this, launch a Service from the BroadcastReceiver and have the Service own the Thread.  A service can last as long as needed.

Comment: hey, Broadcast receiver in itself isn't a thread? What if this guy does all his work in the broadcast receiver itself instead of creating a thread  from thereon?

Comment: No, its not.  It runs on the main (UI) thread.  It also shouldn't be used for long periods-  the assumption is it does the minimal work and returns quickly, there's a timer on the function after which Android will kill the process, especially if others are waiting on the same signal.  If you can't quickly do your work you need to spawn a Service

Comment: I kinda figured this after sometime. Thanks for the reply